# Find peak times with historical data

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to find, on average,  which hours of the day have the most active users on an app. The data includes a timestamp and IDs. I convert the timestamp into a column as a Date (M/d/yy) and another column as an Hour (HH:mm) so that I may find the average users over time by hour.

For example, if on 2/17/2019 at 15:00 there are 6 users, and 2/18/2019 at 15:00 there are 5 users, and 2/19/2019 at 15:00 there are 4 users, the average number of users at 15:00 would be 5. I want to query a table that has every time from 0:00 to 23:45 by 15 minute bins with the average number of users for each time. This is what I have attempted so far but when I calculate it manually the query does not show correct results:

```
Table
| where timestamp > datetime(2018-5-23)
| extend hourNum= format_datetime(bin(timestamp, time(15m)),"HH:mm")
| extend Date= format_datetime(timestamp, "M/d/yy") 
| project timestamp, ID , Date, hourNum
| summarize avgUsers= (dcount(ID)*1.0)/dcount(Date) by hourNum
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the fact that `dcount` is an approximation of the actual distinct count [as per this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction):

**Syntax**

`summarize dcount(Expr [, Accuracy])`

*Arguments*

Expr: Expression that will be used for aggregation calculation.

Accuracy, if specified, controls the balance between speed and accuracy (see Note).

- 0 = the least accurate and fastest calculation. 1.6% error
- 1 = the default, which balances accuracy and calculation time; about 0.8% error.
- 2 = accurate and slow calculation; about 0.4% error.
- 3 = extra accurate and slow calculation; about 0.28% error.
- 4 = super accurate and slowest calculation; about 0.2% error.

You can try going with Accuracy level 4, that should make things closer to the manual calculations.

Alternatively, you can try leveraging double `summarize` (even slower but as precise as it gets):

```
| summarize by ID, hourNum
| summarize count() by hourNum
```

Then, you can join ID count and DateCount on `hourNum` and make a division.

Overall, I'd suggest going with more accurate dcount for simplicity and good enough precision.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your response. I have tried using the accuracy syntax and I get an error. I also am not understanding what you mean by the alternative option so if you could elaborate that would be much appreciated!!

Comment: `| summarize dcount(ID, 2)` should work for accuracy case (tried it locally).

Comment: The suggestion to use two summarize statements to achieve accurate dcount would work like this in full:
`(Table | where … | extend … | summarize by ID, hourNum | summarize DCOUNTID=count() by hourNum) join (Table | where … | extend … | summarize by Date, hourNum | summarize DCOUNTDate=count() by hourNum) on hourNum`

This will give a table with DCOUNTID and DCOUNTDate where you can divide one by another to get the necessary results.